# Chrome extension update

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Just to make sure, 
if I make an update of my extension in the Chrome Web Store, would all the users get the update automatically?

thanks

Comment: Seems like it: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1054246?hl=en.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Google Chrome will attempt to automatically update it. If you change the permissions, the extension will be temporarily disabled and the user will be asked to review the new permissions and re-enable it.

Comment: How long will it take for chrome to disperse the update? Ive jsut tried this and checking on another computer the extension isnt updated.

Comment: @Deekor: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html. It depends on Chrome itself. Apparently, the default frequency is several hours, but you can set it to whatever you want. Again, however, it is browser-dependent, not extension-dependant.